# "Only root can mount" error - but I am root

Tags: arch-linux, samba, shared-disk

Yesterday I was able to mount my smb share with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //XXXX/share /media/share -o user=Ben,password=XXX,workgroup=WORKGROUP,ip=XXX.XX.XX,uid=ben,gid=ben,rw
```

I don't know why it is not working anymore. (Maybe from system update).

I got the following error :

```
mount: only root can mount //XXX.XXX.XXX/share on /home/ben/share
```

I don't know how to fix this problem..

I've also tried to mount it with su -, and Smbclient is working.

I'm Running ArchLinux.

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$EUID"`?

Comment: Have you tried doing `sudo su -` and then run the same command?

Comment: @ChrisDown echo $EUID = 1000

Comment: @BenD - In which case you are not effectively running as root. (Obviously this should be run in the same environment as you are trying to mount in, so you should make sure it is the root shell that is expanding `$EUID`.)

Comment: @Karlson I've tried sudo su- but same result

Comment: @ChrisDown How can I check that ?

Comment: `sudo su -c 'echo "$EUID"'` should do it.

Comment: @ChrisDown When I type su  -c and then echo $EUID I got 0

Comment: @ChrisDown The weird thing is that when I try to mount a local disk it works.

Comment: Samba may act weird if something _else_ is incorrect. Check your credentials, DNS, domain name, etc, add verbose logging. Maybe the problem is not in EUID at all.

Comment: All of these are correct, I can loggin using smbclient and see the content of my HDD. Another solution ?

Comment: Why is the path different between the error message and the mount command?  One is `/media/share` and the other is `/home/ben/share`.  Also, I recomment using `/mnt` for manual or static mounts.  `/media` was created for the HAL/udev daemons to mount dynamically created disks like a USB drive.

Comment: @penguin359 It's just a copy error. Thanks for the 'mnt' advise. However it's still not working.

Comment: As @9000 mentioned, see what verbose mode says by adding a -v to your mount command.  Also check your system logs if you haven't already, and dmesg, and perhaps run an strace on the command for deeper troubleshooting.

Comment: I doubt this is related, apparently [a change in samba disabled setuid](https://bugs.gentoo.org/315445?id=315445) — but this should not be relevant at all if you are already running it with EUID=UID=0...

Comment: Does it have to be samba, have you tried sshfs?

Comment: Have you tried mounting in another path instead /media/share? let´s say something like: /mnt/mysamba?

Comment: Try being root on remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know, what is happen, try strace:

```
sudo strace -f -F -o mount.strace mount -t cifs //XXXX/share /media/share -o user=Ben,password=XXX,workgroup=WORKGROUP,ip=XXX.XX.XX,uid=ben,gid=ben,rw
```

Then try search file `mount.strace` from bottom for some errors, you will obviously found reason... It is hard method, I know...

Answer (score 0):

As I don't see any proper reason for your error, I would propose a slightly different syntax.

First I will create a new directory as root (to be sure root can create it) and then mount the share with slightly different options. Here are the commands (they should all succeed):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/smb_share
sudo touch /mnt/smb_share/test && sudo rm -f /mnt/smb_share/test && echo "Permissions are OK"
sudo mount -t cifs //(hostname)/share /mnt/smb_share -o user=Ben,domain=(WORKGROUP)
```

The mount command should ask you for your Samba user Ben password. I have removed the uid and gid options just to remove some "noise". With this command you should be able to verify that you can mount the share. Of course you need to replace:

- (hostname) by the share server hostname. If it does not work with the hostname, try again but use the IP address instead;
- (WORKGROUP) by your workgroup or domain.

If this work. Try unmounting the share and remounting it with uid only:

```
sudo umount /mnt/smb_share
sudo mount -t cifs //(hostname)/share /mnt/smb_share -o user=Ben,domain=(WORKGROUP),uid=ben
```

If this is working, add the gid, then add the rw and then finally add the password option (step by step). So you can identify which of the options is not understood.